# Error in menu control navigation using sitemap

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I used a menu control for navigation.  I used Sitemap for different login user.  In my local host it's working well, but when I upload my app to the server, it shows an error in web.config.

> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

```
<siteMap>
  <providers>
    <add name="MyNewSitemapProvider"
            type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider"
            siteMapFile="MyNewSitemapFile.sitemap"/>
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Can you please tell me where I made a mistake...

Answer (score 2):

Well ... this just means you're not allowed to add this configuration to your Web.Config file, **unless** you convert your virtual directory to an application.  If you have access to IIS manager, do the following:

- Right click on your application's folder within the IIS browser.
- Click "Convert to Application" and follow the instructions
- Now refresh your page, and it should work.

Comment: @user1285783: If this worked for you, mark this answer as accepted to improve your accept rating and to recognize the help of fellow user.

Answer (score 0):

You somehow need to create an application for the site.  If you have control of the machine, you can do it in IIS.  Otherwise the hoster probably has a tool to set that up for you.